# Passing new string through GUI matlab

Tags: matlab

So i recently created a GUI designed to do some basic image processing. It uses

```
[filename, pathname] = ...
     uigetfile({'*.m';'*.mdl';'*.mat';'*.*'},'File Selector');

set(handles.Textbox1, 'string', fullfile(pathname,filename));
```

to get the file name, then places it in a textbox on the GUI for other functions to use. I have a noise function designed to add noise to the inputted picture, but I can't seem to figure out how I can make the GUI use the newly create noise photo for the rest of the filters.

Let me explain a little bit, there are 6 buttons on my gui, each designed to preform some function on the picture, such as mean filtering/laplachian filtering etc, and one button that adds noise. After clicking the button, a figure pops up with the desired effect on the image. What I would like to do, is after clicking the "add noise" button, have the GUI use the new picture for any further image processing. For instance, if I clicked add noise, then mean filtering right now, the GUI would spit out two images, one with noise, one mean filtered. My goal is for the GUI to instead preform the mean filtering on the noise filled picture.

I have tried to add the following to the "Addnoise" function that I wrote, but nothing happens.

```
saveas(myimage, 'photonoise.raw');
```

After saving the image, I need to pass the string of the new image back to the original program so it can do the processing, but am unsure on how to save, and open the string. I would prefer if after clicking the addnoise button, the old string would simply be replaced, without having to reopen the file browser and select the new image so I do not want to use

```
[filename, pathname] = ...
     uigetfile({'*.m';'*.mdl';'*.mat';'*.*'},'File Selector');

set(handles.Textbox1, 'string', fullfile(pathname,filename));
```

again. Assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Handles struct to your advantage and save the image data to your handles.

```
handles.currentImage=imread(get(handles.textbox1,'string')); %This reads in an image

handles.currentImage=yourOperation(handles.currentImage) % Modify your image and save back

figure(1) %This keeps everything popping up in 1 figure, 
%if you dont want that, remove the "(1)"

imshow(handles.currentImage) %show current image
```

Comment: And use imwrite to save your images, do "help imwrite" to figure out how to use it

Comment: I have done what you said, but how can I update the string in my textbox to that of the new image? The string is not changing.

Comment: You don't have to anymore. A string just represents the image file name. imread reads in the image, so the file name is no longer important. The file name is not going to change. We are using the actual data from the image (stored in handles.currentImage) so the filename is no longer doing anything.

If I have misinterpreted your question, the answer is think about how you set that textbox string in the first place.... Now how do you think you would set it again? ;)

Comment: I understand that I could set the string again in the same manner to which I did earlier, but I was hoping there was a way to have the new string automatically appear in textbox1, replacing the old string without the user having to reinput the new image with the added noise.

Comment: Ok it is unnecessary to save your noisy image, as I have mentioned several times, there is no need to actually save the image if you just reuse the data in handles.currentImage..    ..BUT IF YOU INSIST ON SAVING, simply do imwrite(handles.currentImage, 'photonoise.raw','png'); and then do set(handles.Textbox1, 'string', 'photonoise.raw');

Comment: Honestly just looking at an example may help you tremendously, just look at the MATLAB File Exchange, there are SO many files doing the exact same thing you are, so you can get some ideas and suggestions on how to do it from there.

Comment: And lastly, I just realized you misunderstood by "do it the same way you set it in the first place" OF COURSE YOU DONT HAVE TO LOAD A NEW IMAGE TO RESET THE STRING!! Update it like this: set(handles.Textbox1, 'string', 'whatever darn string you want can go here!');

Comment: Sounds good, sorry for getting crabby, it's hard to remember being so new to MATLAB, just keep reading that documentation, seriously. haha

Comment: Actually, one more thing. You have it writing a file called "photonoise.raw.png", which doesnt really make any sense. Is there a way to write it just a .raw?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32033/discussion-between-user2475404-and-shaun314)